# I don't understand one line in problem to prove $|2^S| = 2^{|S|}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, induction, proof-explanation

Problem to prove by induction:

If $ S $ is a finite set, then $\vert 2^S \vert = 2^{\vert S \vert}$

Proof:

Induction on size of $S$, call it $n$ , $n \ge 0$.

**Base case:** Suppose $n=0$. Now, $|2^S| = \vert\{\emptyset\}\vert  = 1 $ and $2^{\vert S \vert} = 2^0 = 1 $ so base case works.
**Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume $\vert 2^S \vert = 2^{\vert S \vert}$ for set $S$ of size $k \ge 0$.
**Inductive Step:** We want to show that $S'$ of size $k+1$ has $2 ^{k+1}$ elements.
S' has one more element than S, let's call it $x$. We know $S$ has size $2^k$ so,
 $S' = S $ +  $($extra subsets with $ x $$)$
$\vert S\ |= 2^k +$ number of subsets with $x$   *; by Inductive Hypothesis*
**Number of subsets with x is also $2^k$**,so
$\vert S\ |= 2^k + 2^k = 2(2^k) = 2^{k+1}$

My misunderstanding is this line:
Number of subsets with $x$ is also $2^k$
How can we assume this? How is it possible to deduce this without "making it up" or how to justify this line?

Thank you anyone that helps. It's been a while since I did proofs and trying to do a bit of review and exercises. I got this proof from: [Answer](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/an-introduction-to-formal-languages-and-automata-5th-edition-solutions-9781449615529)

Comment: Consider: $S=\{1,2,3\}, |S|=3, 2^{|S|}=2^3$. Then: $T=\{1,2,3,x\}, |T|=4, 2^{|T|}=2^4$. Indeed: $\{x\}, \{x,1\}, \{x,2\}, \{x,3\}, \{x,1,2\}, \{x,1,3\}, \{x,2,3\}, \{x,1,2,3\} \Rightarrow 2^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Each subset of $S'$ that contains $x$ has all other elements from $S$. Each such subset, thus, can be written as the union of a unique subset of $S$ and the set $\{x\}$. Moreover, no two distinct subsets of $S$ will generate the same subset of $S'$ on union with $\{x\}$. This means that the number of subsets of $S'$ containing $x$ is equal to the number of subsets of $S$.